# Change the site(file) but not the link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, screen, resolution

I have made a site but two other subsites for different screen resolution. e.g. index.htm(for 1080p resolution) and index1.htm(for 720p resolution).

so

index.htm is open when somebody types www.mysite.com

index1.htm is open when somebody types www.mysite.com/index1.htm or his screen resolution is 720p

but I don't want to be like these

I want both to detect visitors screen resolution (i know how), and automatically to open one (e.g index1.htm but the link not to change and stay www.mysite.com [not www.mysite.com/index1.htm])

Comment: Try googling 'media queries'.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `media-queries` to make sites look good in every resolution. Some tutorials:

- Webdesignerwalls: [CSS3 media-queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) and [Responsive design with CSS3 media queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries)
- Nettuts+: [A crash course in CSS media-queries](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-a-crash-course-in-css-media-queries/)
- CSS tricks: [CSS media-queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and [Screencast about responsive web design](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/102-braindump-on-responsive-web-design/)
- Some great examples: http://mediaqueri.es/

---

For those who find this topic while searching about this problem on Google. You need something like AJAX to get this done.
If you only change de stylesheet on different resolutions you can use a Stylesheet Switcher.

But if you change the total HTML, which is not good for your usabilty, you need to put everything in the `body` in special files and load them in the body with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with media queries, you only need one index.html and one stylesheet. Read this article for more info!
[Media queries tutorial](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries)